# Is it possible to have a public user login and a private user login for Communities?

Tags: community, security

This may be a simple/redundant question, but I am trying to set up ONE community with Public access for one group of individuals and regular login for a Private Group of individuals, lets call them Teachers (Private) vs Students (Public).

Is this possible to do in one Communities org, or does it make more sense/easier to break this out into two communities?

Answer (score 2):

Its definitely possible to handle this in single org and one communities .The pages you want to expose to the guest user you can make them public while those you want only teachers to have access will be protected and will require a login and use community license .

Comment: Agreed. In terms of access, what is the best way to allow for Teachers to sign in (Profile?) vs the Students who do not need to sign in at all to access Student only content - Is this something in Administration I must configure?

Comment: Are you using templates for your community or using force.com sites ?

Comment: I am using the Napili template.

Comment: Ya so in Napili there is a checkbox on each of those pages to make it public .Also in advanced settings make it public so that whole community is public and if you want variations of same page use page variations .